# How to send ctrl+D into Emacs' Eshell?

Tags: emacs, eshell

How to send ctrl+D into Emacs' Eshell? It looks like Emacs intercepts all my attempts to send any control key + a letter to shell and tries to interpret it as it's own command. How to send that combination to Emacs' EShell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the specific case of <kbd>C-d</kbd>, you can use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-d</kbd>, which is bound to `eshell-send-eof-to-process`. Otherwise, use <kbd>C-q</kbd> for quoted-insert, to force the following character to be inserted into the buffer even if it has a key binding in Emacs.